# What's the correct usage of generic wildcards when defining functional Java APIs?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, generic-method

I'm writing functional-style static helper methods acting as operators for a generic abstraction (say `Iterable<T>`), and I'm a bit confused about when I should use wildcards. What are the correct, most type-safe and simplest method signatures in the following cases, and why?

- Checking properties:

`public static int size(Iterable<?> source)`

vs.

`public static <T> int size(Iterable<T> source)`

- Transforming:

`public static <T> Iterable<T> take(Iterable<T> source, int count)`

vs.

`public static <T> Iterable<T> take(Iterable<? extends T> source, int count)`

- Combining:

`public static boolean elementsEqual(Iterable<?> first, Iterable<?> second)`

vs.

`public static <T> boolean elementsEqual(Iterable<T> first, Iterable<T> second)`

vs.

`public static <T> boolean elementsEqual(Iterable<? extends T> first, Iterable<? extends T> second)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static <T> int size(Iterable<T> source)
```

is equivalent to

```
public static int size(Iterable<?> source)
```

as long as you don't need to refer to `T` in the method implementation.  I'd err towards the `?`, just because it reduces clutter.

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> take(Iterable<? extends T> source, int count)
```

is the more general, and it should work in both cases, so I'd go ahead with that one.

```
public static boolean elementsEqual(Iterable<?> first, Iterable<?> second)
```

is appropriate because `Object.equals(Object)` doesn't have a narrowed signature.

([Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [provides](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) many of these methods; you could use that as a reference if you like.  Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: There is a case to be made for `public static <T, S extends T> Iterable<T> take(Iterable<S> source, int count)` which lets the compiler infer the type arguments for `Iterable<Number> nums = take(ints, 3);`.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding comparison: isn't specifying a generic type more type-safe as described here? http://rickyclarkson.blogspot.de/2006/12/making-equalsobject-type-safe.html

Comment: No, not really; that article is based on the (false) premise that objects of different types should always be unequal.  It is right and proper that e.g. a `LinkedList<Integer>` can equal an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and that `Object.equals` takes an `Object` argument.